# Postfix blocking mail from backup MX

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, backup, mx-record

I have two CentOS 6.6 servers configured with Postfix for sending email. I have everything working great, SPF entries, Domain Keys and OpenDKIM configured and working, but I'm trying to perfect my backup mail server. Currently, if I shutdown mx1 and send an email, it gets queued up on mx2 like it's supposed to. Once I start Postfix on mx1, the mail gets sent out, but mx1 rejects it because of the SPF filter. I've tried everything I can to get this working, but it's just not working the way it's supposed to.

mx2 is configured to relay mail for the domain I'm sending to. I also have the IP of the backup MX in mynetwork in my main.cf

> mx1 = bluemoon.domain.tld
>
> mx2 = surly.domain.tld

Logs:

mx2:

```
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly postfix/smtpd[13015]: 4B37B35E1092E: client=sender1.zohomail.com[74.201.84.162]
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly postfix/cleanup[13020]: 4B37B35E1092E: message-id=<004d01d081b6$847140b0$8d53c210$@larsonit.net>
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: SKIP during call 'limit-out' handler
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Apr 28 08:23:31 surly spf filter[13024]: Starting spf filter...
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly spf filter[13024]: SPF result: pass
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly spf filter[13024]: SPF status: PASS
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[23410]: PASS during call 'spf' handler
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly opendkim[680]: 4B37B35E1092E: sender1.zohomail.com [<IP ADDR>] not internal
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly opendkim[680]: 4B37B35E1092E: not authenticated
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly opendkim[680]: 4B37B35E1092E: no signature data
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly postfix/qmgr[2080]: 4B37B35E1092E: from=<jon@otherdomain.tld>, size=3236, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly postfix/smtp[13025]: connect to mx1.domain.tld[<IP ADDR>]:25: Connection refused
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly postfix/smtpd[13015]: disconnect from sender1.zohomail.com[74.201.84.162]
Apr 28 08:23:32 surly postfix/smtp[13025]: 4B37B35E1092E: to=<jon@MAILDOMAIN.TLD>, relay=none, delay=1.4, delays=1.3/0.01/0.02/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx1.domain.tld[<ip addr>]:25: Connection refused)
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/qmgr[2080]: 4B37B35E1092E: from=<jon@larsonit.net>, size=3236, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/smtp[13025]: 4B37B35E1092E: to=<jon@maildomain.tld>, relay=mx1.domain.tld[<ip addr>]:25, delay=51, delays=50/0/0.04/0.6, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx1.domain.tld[<ip adr>] said: 550 5.7.1 Command rejected (in reply to end of DATA command))
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/cleanup[13020]: D1B1C35E10940: message-id=<20150428132421.D1B1C35E10940@surly.larsonit-hosts.net>
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/qmgr[2080]: D1B1C35E10940: from=<>, size=5422, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/bounce[13050]: 4B37B35E1092E: sender non-delivery notification: D1B1C35E10940
Apr 28 08:24:21 surly postfix/qmgr[2080]: 4B37B35E1092E: removed
```

mx1:

```
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 postfix/smtpd[27039]: connect from surly.domain.tld[<ip>]
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 postfix/smtpd[27039]: 3A2F9708C90E: client=surly.domain.tld[<Ip>]
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 postfix/cleanup[27044]: 3A2F9708C90E: message-id=<004d01d081b6$847140b0$8d53c210$@larsonit.net>
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: SKIP during call 'limit-out' handler
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 spf filter[27047]: Starting spf filter...
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 spf filter[27047]: SPF result: softfail
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 spf filter[27047]: SPF status: REJECT
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: handlers_stderr: REJECT
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[19488]: REJECT during call 'spf' handler
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 postfix/cleanup[27044]: 3A2F9708C90E: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from surly.<domain.tld>[<ip addr>]: 5.7.1 Command rejected; from=<jon@othedomain.tld> to=<jon@maildomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<surly.domain.tld>
```

Comment: Backup MX hosts shouldn't be necessary anymore. They're more often than not used to deliver spam as the backup is either configured less stringently than the primary and/or because the primary doesn't check what comes in from the backup MX. I don't use them anymore, I just trust I can get the primary back online within 48 hours if anything bad happens.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this log

```
Apr 28 08:24:21 s18267928 postfix/cleanup[27044]: 3A2F9708C90E: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from surly.<domain.tld>[<ip addr>]: 5.7.1 Command rejected; from=<jon@othedomain.tld> to=<jon@maildomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<surly.domain.tld>
```

apparently the email rejected by Plesk milter that invoked by postfix. So we have two options here:

1. Exclude IP address from so postfix won't deliver email to milter-checking.

   Unfortunately there are [no direct parameter](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Exclude-recipients-from-pre-queue-spamass-milter-checks-tp43565p43566.html) to control this. There are workaround involving setup new `smtpd` service in `master.cf` and add [no_milters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#no_milters) parameter. See [this documentation](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter) for example.
2. Tell plesk to whitelist the particular IP Address from SPF Checks.

According to this thread: [Any way to turn off SPF checking on Plesk for a specific IP?](http://forum.odin.com/threads/any-way-to-turn-off-spf-checking-on-plesk-for-a-specific-ip.325347/), it is possible to whitelist the particular IP Address from SPF Checks. Just set

```
ip4:a.b.c.d
```

in **SPF local rules** option.